# CL_BCS does not send a sent request

Tags: abap

I was trying to send email and send request but only the email was sent(SBWP). I'm expecting to receive a send request in transaction SOSA.

```
  SELECT-OPTIONS:
   s_inbox FOR bname NO INTERVALS,     "SAP ID
   s_email FOR bname NO INTERVALS.     "External Email
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1.
```

*Code for sending the email to list of users. LIKE CC/BCC in email. Users listed under the S_INBOX were able to receive an email in the workplace inbox in SBWP.

```
  LOOP AT s_inbox[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<s_inbox>).
    lo_sender = cl_sapuser_bcs=>create( <s_inbox>-low ).
    lo_send_request->add_recipient( lo_sender ).
  ENDLOOP.
```

*Code for sending an outbound send request in transaction code SOSA. User or users under this list s_email were not able to receive an email or outbound send request in SOSA.

```
  LOOP AT s_email[] ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<s_email>).
    lo_recipient = cl_sapuser_bcs=>create( <s_email>-low ).
    lo_send_request->add_recipient( lo_recipient ).
  ENDLOOP.
```

INBOX IS S_INBOX

EMAIL IS S_EMAIL

[image]

When the program is executed, there should be a send request received here. If it was sent today 16/08/2022, there should be a send request here but there was none.
[image]

Comment: It look you are using WILLIAMS and sender and checking sender as KRAMER.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you ever succeed to send an email from you SAP system/client? (note that SBWP doesn't prove that emails are sent, SAP messages are different from emails) If no, first ask an administrator to check the configuration of SCOT and SMTP.

Comment: Also ensure that you are calling `COMMIT WORK` after the call to the `send()` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only the first user is selected from the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329138/only-the-first-user-is-selected-from-the-input)